# App caching for tab app not working in the new Microsoft Teams after switching to new Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

App caching for tab app was working fine in the old Teams with '*registerOnLoadHandler*' and '*registerBeforeUnloadHandler*' handlers which keep app cached to load faster on tab switches. But after switching to the new Teams the app caching is not working as expected. The tab app reloads on all the tab switches. Is there any way to get the app caching functionality in new Teams app.

I have tried registerBeforeSuspendOrTerminateHandler and registerOnResumeHandler handlers but it was not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently [App caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/app-caching) isn't supported in the new Teams client.

Please refer this below documentation for known issues:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/teams-updates#known-issues